# Update/Replace with a substring - triple backslashes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column full of duplicate filepaths:

```
\\C:\298788\DOC1\SUB1\\\C:\298788\DOC1\SUB1\FILE.txt
\\C:\298788\DOC1\SUB1\\\C:\298788\DOC1\SUB1\FILE.txt
\\C:\298788\DOC1\SUB1\\\C:\298788\DOC1\SUB1\FILE.txt
```

I need only the second part of the string ie. `C:\298788\DOC1\SUB1\FILE.txt`

How do I replace up to the triple backslashes with nothing. I have tried:

```
UPDATE [TABLE].[dbo].[ColumnName]
SET [ColumnName] = REPLACE([ColumnName], '%\\\', '');
```

It says all rows updated however nothing has changed. Assuming its something to do with the backslashes.

Using SQL SERVER 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stuff()`

```
select col = stuff(col,1,charindex('\\\',col,2)+2,'')
from tbl
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QRKWP8606

returns:

```
+------------------------------+
|             col              |
+------------------------------+
| C:\298788\DOC1\SUB1\FILE.txt |
| C:\298788\DOC1\SUB1\FILE.txt |
| C:\298788\DOC1\SUB1\FILE.txt |
+------------------------------+
```

---

as an `update`:

```
update tbl
  set col = stuff(col,1,charindex('\\\',col,2)+2,'')
where charindex('\\\',col,2)>0
```

Comment: Thanks but I only need the second half of the string, after '\\\'. I want to replace everything before and including '\\\' with nothing basically.

Comment: @Elnombre My mistake, updated answer to use `stuff()`

Comment: Works great thanks a lot! Just can't upvote you yet.